# Hiding scrollbar on Mozilla with margin-right messes up the content

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I've hidden my scrollbar on Chrome with this piece of code:

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent; 
  }
```

And I found that the best way to hide it in Firefox is to set margin-right: -16px on the parent div. And in Firefox, that looks great. However, the issue is now in Chrome because it moves the entire content inside the parent div to right. If I try to fix it by adding margin-right: 16px to the container inside the parent div, then it messes things up in Firefox.

I'm sure you've encountered this before, but is there anything I can do to fix this? Any known solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: First of all, do you want to hide your scrollbar but still scroll into your page?

Comment: If you just want to visually hide the scrollbar and still allow user to scroll with mouse or keyboard, you can try the following css: `html {overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;}`

Comment: @brian17han that worked! I can't believe I couldn't find that anywhere. Everywhere I looked, they just advised to hide it with margin-right. Can you please post is as an answer so I can accept it as a correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to visually hide the scrollbar and still allow user to scroll with mouse or keyboard, you can try the following css:

```
html {
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just give padding only for chrome

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent; 
    -webkit-padding-end: 16px;
  }
```

Or just set `-webkit-padding-end: 16px;` on the parent div .
And you can use the same idea on Firefox also , Just setup this

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    parent div {
        margin-right: -16px;
    }
}
```

So the margin get only Firefox and you don't anything to change .

@-moz-scrollbars-none If you go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow and look at the Mozilla Extensions section, it says that "-moz-scrollbars-none" is "an obsolete API and is no longer guaranteed to work."  Better to go with an approach that is more stable.